# Сделать [рефакторинг] синонимом [инспекция-кода] метки

Tags: предложение, метки, инспекция-кода

Не ясно зачем отдельно [[рефакторинг]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3/info) и [[инспекция-кода]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info) метки существуют. Предлагаю их [объединить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/synonyms) <- по ссылке можно проголосовать «за»/«против» создания синонима.

Comment: Вообще-то это разные вопросы, инспекция кода шире, чем рефакторинги.

Comment: Там еще и [tag:refactoring] есть...

Comment: @AK предлагаете добавить ко всем рефакторинг вопросам ещё и метку инспекция-кода если речь об улучшении конкретного кода?

Answer (score 4):

Нет, они совершенно разные. Метка [рефакторинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) должна быть про рефакторинг кода, в том числе общие принципы рефакторинга и подходы к нему. По аналогии с [функциональное-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

А [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) — это когда есть готовый конкретный фрагмент кода и его просят оценить.

Comment: Ваш ответ создаёт впечатление что вы не читали описания меток (не могу поверить). Вы знакомы со сайтом code-review.SE? Какие вопросы там публикуются? инспекция-кода включает и рефакторинг. Приведите ссылку на Мета обсуждение где разрешили рефакторинг вопросы, если вы считаете что они отдельны от инспекция-кода вопросов — иначе эти вопросы были бы off-topic на Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jfs, у метки [tag:рефакторинг] описание неверное/недописанное.

Comment: @jfs вопросы про рефакторинг - частный случай вопросов про программирование, а они точно разрешены

Comment: @PavelMayorov вопросы об улучшении кода были явно разрешены если они имеют метку инспекция-кода. Существует большая разница между Stack Overflow вопросом и Code Review вопросом. По ссылкам приведённым выше пройдите.

Comment: @jfs какое отношение вопросы об улучшении кода имют к метку "рефакторинг"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы прочтите описание метки, посмотрите какие вопросы люди задают фактически (не все, но многие принадлежат не на Stack Overflow, а на code-review.SE, что на русском SO транслируется в инспекция-кода метку).