# Объединить метки рефакторинг и refactoring

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Мы как-то [говорили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6497/213987) про то является ли [рефакторинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) синонимом к [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), но не заметили, что у нас рефакторингов два штуки: [рефакторинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) и [refactoring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring).

Предлагаю классическое решение: сделать русскоязычную метку основной, англоязычную синонимом.

Comment: Тут все очевидно, объединяйте! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Синонимизировал и объединил. Кеш должен скоро обновиться.